# ElasticSearch and highlighting performance - plain vs. fast vector highlighter

Tags: performance, lucene, elasticsearch, highlighting

I am running into performance issues when running a query that uses both slop and the fact vector highlighter.  Interestingly, the performance issue goes away when performing the same query with the plain highlighter, and I am not sure why this is the case.

Here's the metadata for the field being searched:

```
contents: {
   store: true
   search_analyzer: mySearchAnalyzer
   term_vector: with_positions_offsets
   type: string
}
```

The following query, which uses the fact vector highlighter, takes over 60 seconds:

```
{
  "size": 500,
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "\"CATERPILLAR FINANCIAL SERVICES ASIA PTE LTD\"~5",
      "fields": [
        "contents"
      ],
      "default_operator": "and",
    }
  },
  "highlight": {
    "fields": {
      "contents": {}
    }
  }
}
```

However, if I change the query to use the plain analyzer, then it takes only a few milliseconds:

```
{
  "size": 500,
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "\"CATERPILLAR FINANCIAL SERVICES ASIA PTE LTD\"~5",
      "fields": [
        "contents"
      ],
      "default_operator": "and",
    }
  },
  "highlight": {
    "fields": {
      "contents": {"type" : "plain"}
    }
  }
}
```

I have looked at different options for the highlighters (like fragment_size, fragment_offset, phrase_limit), but nothing is immediately obvious as what can be set to improve performance.

Any ideas on what is going on here?  Or what type of settings I can try to improve the performance?

Note: One reason we switched from the plain to fact vector highlighter was due to some queries failing with the plain highlighter.

**Edit**: I've added the reproduction steps which demonstrate the issue in the following link:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-IfDOojIDnIQmpkY2RNN2pMREE/edit?usp=sharing

I think the key is that there is a field which contains lots of similar values (e.g. in this case, Caterpillar is referenced many times).

Comment: I used with_positions_offsets for around 20M records and no problem so far. It even faster than `plain`. Can you post the avg number of records and avg length of `content` ? Also the definition of `mySearchAnalyzer`. Would be good if you write a full bash script that createindex/inputsomerecords/query and put it on gist for easy in analyse.

Comment: That's a good idea.  I've added the reproduction steps here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-IfDOojIDnIQmpkY2RNN2pMREE/edit?usp=sharing.  Notice that there only needs to be a small amount of data to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Sorry quiet busy with company project. Now just have some free time to come back. I recreated the index and cannot reproduce the issue, maybe b.c the data is not enough. BTW did you try `postings highlighter` (0.90.6+) ? Let try it b.c your contents look very long

Answer (score 0):

While not strictly an answer, based on comments from Duc.Duong in which he was not able to reproduce the issue, I tried reproducing this with the version we are using (0.90.3) and the latest versopm (1.3.2).  It turns out that this no longer reproduces with the latest version - that the search returns right away.

So, bottom line, this issue does not reproduce with the latest version.  Not sure where it was fixed, but the problem occurs in 0.90.3.